# How do I know that min-term can't be combined any further?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to learn (and implement) Quine-McCluskey algorithm for boolean function minimalisation. I'm learning the algorithm from [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm#Step_1:_finding_prime_implicants).

From that I understood the following:

1. Take all `1`s and `don't care`s from table and put them in tiny table, ordered by number of `1`s in the variables.
2. Any two rows that are only different by 1 digit can be combined. The diferent digit doesn't matter then:

<sub>Highlighter is broken. Doesn't highlight the code if this line doesn't exist.</sub>

```
 m8     | 1000
 m9     | 1001
 -------------
 m(8,9) | 100-
```

Now here, the wiki also states that the expressions that *can't be combined any further shall be marked by `*`*. But in their example, why can't `m(4,12) = -100` be combined any further? Can't I combine it with `m(8,9) = 100-` producing  `--0-`?

Comment: I agree that the Wikipedia article does not make it clear that two expressions can only be combined if there is exactly one position where they differ and in that position one expression has a 1 and the other has a 0. The paper by McLuskey referenced in the article is available online and is very clear.